# SData - SalesLogix

Tags: saleslogix, sdata

Are there any SalesLogix Web developers in here?

If so, here is my question:

On Sage's SData page [HERE](http://sdata.sage.com/sdatacore_showcases.html) there is a demo of Self-service Website using SData. Can some one direct me where or how do I begin to make this happen. I am currently working on a project (SalesLogix related project) and SData is direction I would like to go. I am knowledgeable in web development but not very much in SalesLogix. Can someone direct me what I need to make my site talk to SData?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to grab the SData libraries from GitHub:
https://github.com/Sage/SDataCSharpClientLib

And depending on your requirements, you might not even need SData; SubLogix might work for you as well. If you have VS2010 you can download it as a package from NuGet.

Here's some information on SubLogix. It works very well as far as I've used it (for small 3rd party libraries where I didn't want to deal with the headaches of setting up SData and ProcessHost).

http://customerfx.com/pages/crmdeveloper/2010/09/14/introducing-sublogix-a-simple-net-repository-for-saleslogix-applications.aspx

Comment: Thank you E. Rodriguez, funny thing is that I have account at CustomerFX and I follow Ryan Farley for a while but I totally forgot about SubLogix.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks E for the mention of Sublogix :-)

BTW, I wanted to point out that you can also get SDataCSharpClientLib on NuGet now as well. In  the Add Package Reference dialog just search for SData or Sage and you'll find it.

Comment: Ryan I am your biggest fan. I can't believe that you just commented on my question.